# Why are AskDifferent and AskDifferentMeta not retinafied yet?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

Being sites for Apple related questions, you would think that AskDifferent and AskDifferentMeta would be retinafied by now. But they aren't. And they look terrible on retina MacBook Pros!

Are there plans to do this any time soon?

Comment: I do know all 94 http://stackexchange.com sites are designed and maintained by one designer. Even if this is on the roadmap, it might be out a ways yet. The site owners see questions on this meta, so an answer more recent than this [comment from May 12](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131045/optimise-stack-exchange-user-flair-for-retina-displays) or whether the [job opening for a product designer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/10/join-the-stack-exchange-team-were-hiring/) to work with [Jin](http://stackexchange.com/users/21721/jin) has been filled might let them schedule this work

Comment: Also, would you consider listing some specific items you would like to see scaled for retina? I'm going to edit the language since I see things as being able to look better and more precise to match the text since terrible is in the eye of the beholder. Some people love low resolution artwork :)

Comment: I am not happy with the edit but... okay.

Comment: Feel free to revert my edit, but also have a look at the FAQ - this site is very much community edited and some of the specifics about your assumptions didn't fit for everyone here.

Comment: Even so the first rule of edits is "respect the original author". That implies not diluting or changing the sentiment of the question.

Comment: If you had said "I would expect" instead of implying that everyone here "you would expect" I wouldn't have chosen to change the sentiment and tone of your question. Seriously - just edit it back if you feel you want a more cranky tone and are deprived of that voice.

Comment: "You would think/expect" is just an idiom; not to be taken literally. I am reverting the edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is on my todo list for this year. When I do it'd be rolling out for all sites at once.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the confirmation that it's on the plate for sometime in 2013.